# To what extent does halacha dictate the relationship between a male rabbi and a female congregant?

Tags: tznius-modesty, niddah, contemporary-halacha, yichud-seclusion

Which, if any, halachot of "Tzniut" apply to the relationship between a rabbi and a female congregant?

From what I understand, it is common for a husband to bring his wife's undergarments to a rabbi for him to examine and determine if she has the status of "niddah". Is the woman allowed to bring it to the rabbi herself (not just to drop it off, but to have him examine it in her presence)? Can the woman have a private conversation with the rabbi about intimate matters or does her husband have to be present?

Where are these halachot, if any, written about?

Comment: If anything the rules are stricter so as to avoid even an appearance of impropriety (cf Shkalim 3:2)

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Nedarim.20b.6 - women who came to Rebbi and Rav, to discuss marital issues in the bedroom